# Does the length of the path tend to $0$ when deriving the boundary conditions for Electrostatic Fields?

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions

In "Introduction to Electrodynamics", Griffiths provides a loose justification for the continuity of the component of electrostatic fields tangential to a surface charge distribution that goes as follows.

For electrostatic fields, $$\oint \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=0$$ for any closed loop. Consider the following closed loop which passes through the surface charge distribution[image: loop within the charged surface]

In the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ the contributions from the sides (the edges passing into the loop) goes to $0$ and the sides give $E^{\|}_{\textrm{above}}l-E^{\|}_{\textrm{below}}l$ Which means that
$$\mathbf{E}^{\|}_{\textrm{above}}=\mathbf{E}^{\|}_{\textrm{below}}$$
I'm not sure I understand why the contributions from the top and the bottom can be replaced with $E^{\|}_{\textrm{above}}l$ and -$E^{\|}_{\textrm{below}}l$ respectively. Is this because the length $l$ is being considered as small enough that $\mathbf{E}$ is constant? Wouldn't that mean that $(E^{\|}_{\textrm{above}}-E^{\|}_{\textrm{below}})l$ would go to $0$ regardless of the values of $\mathbf{E}$ since $l$ is going to $0$ (being considered arbitrarily small)?

Comment: But $l$ isn't going to $0$. It's just $\epsilon$ that is going to $0$

Comment: How can one make the contribution from the top and bottom edges $E^{\|}_{\textrm{above}}l$ and $-E^{\|}_{\textrm{above}}l$ if the electric field is a function of position if $l$ (or the surface?). Wouldn't the line integral have to account for the different values of $\mathbf{E}$ if $l$ wasn't considered to be infinitesimal?

Comment: Try writing something just like this $\vec E^{\|}_{above} l -\vec E^{\|}_{below} l=0$ can you get what you wanted?

Comment: But $l$ isn't infinitesimal here. I'm still not following.

Comment: What justifies writing the line integral as $(E^{\|}_{\textrm{above}}-E^{\|}_{\textrm{below}})l$ if the surface is arbitrary and $\mathbf{E}$ can vary along the length $l$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some remarks first: no, the electric field cannot be considered approximately constant along the "horizontal" sides. Rather, we're applying the mean-value theorem for integrals. After that, yes, we have to shrink the length of the curve to $0$ as well.

For the rest of the discussion, let us fix a point $p$ on the surface, and consider a "rectangular" loop "centered" at $p$. The "top" line segment can be parametrized by some (smooth injective immersion, i.e derivative nowhere vanishing) curve $\gamma_{\epsilon}$, and for the sake of definiteness, let us parametrize it by the interval $[0,1]$, i.e $\gamma_{\epsilon}:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}^3$. Note that I indicate the subscript $\epsilon$ because for each $\epsilon>0$ we have a different "rectangular" loop. Then, the integral over the top portion is given by the line integral
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}&=\int_0^1\mathbf{E}(\gamma_{\epsilon}(t))\cdot \gamma_{\epsilon}'(t)\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1\underbrace{\bigg(\mathbf{E}(\gamma_{\epsilon}(t))\cdot \frac{\gamma_{\epsilon}'(t)}{\|\gamma_{\epsilon}'(t)\|}\bigg)}_{:=f(t)}\, \underbrace{\|\gamma_{\epsilon}'(t)\|}_{:=g(t)}\,dt
\end{align}
here the $\cdot$ refers to the dot product. Now away from the surface charge, the electric field behaves pretty nicely, so $\mathbf{E}$ is certainly continuous along the curve, and therefore, $f(t)$ is a continuous function of the parameter $t$, and $g$ is continuous simply because the curve $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ is. So, we have an intergal $\int_0^1f(t)g(t)\,dt$ where $f,g$ are continuous and $g> 0$, doesn't change sign. This is more than enough to apply [first mean-value theorem for Riemann integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals). The theorem tells us that there is some point $c_{\epsilon}\in [0,1]$ (depending on $\epsilon$ since everything here depends on $\epsilon$)  such that $\int_0^1f(t)g(t)\,dt=f(c_{\epsilon})\int_0^1g(t)\,dt$. But now note that integrating $g$ means we're integrating the speed of the curve $\|\gamma_{\epsilon}'(t)\|$, and thus we get the length of the curve. Therefore, there is some $c_{\epsilon}\in [0,1]$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}&=f(c_{\epsilon})\cdot \text{length of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$}\\
&=\bigg(\mathbf{E}(\gamma_{\epsilon}(c_{\epsilon}))\cdot \frac{\gamma_{\epsilon}'(c_{\epsilon})}{\|\gamma_{\epsilon}'(c_{\epsilon})\|}\bigg) \,\text{length of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$}.
\end{align}
Now, look carefully at what is in big brackets. We're taking the dot product of $\mathbf{E}$ (evaluated at the point $\gamma_{\epsilon}(c_{\epsilon})$, which lies above the surface) with the unit tangent vector along the curve. In other words, we're taking the parallel component of the electric field, at some point above the surface charge and multiplying by the length of the curve. You have a similar story for the "bottom" portion of the loop. And eventually, you get the minus sign because  of the orientation of the loops.

In short, what I've just done is provide the proof of the mean-value theorem for line integrals: for any vector field $\mathbf{F}$ and any nice curve $\gamma$, we have $\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$ equals the tangential component of the vector field along the curve, at some intermediate point of the curve, times the length of the curve. (This should intuitively make sense; otherwise, go back to the basic vanilla case of the mean-value theorem; Khan Academy and many other sites have good intuitive explanations).

Now, by doing the same thing at the bottom side, we find that by taking the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$ (remember that the other two sides don't contribute)
\begin{align}
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \bigg(\mathbf{E}(\gamma_{\epsilon}(c_{\epsilon}))\cdot \frac{\gamma_{\epsilon}'(c_{\epsilon})}{\|\gamma_{\epsilon}'(c_{\epsilon})\|}\bigg)\cdot \text{length of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$}\\
&=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \bigg(\mathbf{E}(\gamma_{-\epsilon}(c_{-\epsilon}))\cdot \frac{\gamma_{-\epsilon}'(c_{-\epsilon})}{\|\gamma_{-\epsilon}'(c_{-\epsilon})\|}\bigg)\cdot \text{length of $\gamma_{-\epsilon}$}
\end{align}
I indicate the minus sign in the subscript $\gamma_{-\epsilon}$ to mean that we're at the "bottom side". Now, if we set things up correctly (i.e with appropriate smoothness of $(\epsilon,t)\mapsto \gamma_{\epsilon}(t)$) and with uniform convergence of the curve and the derivatives, then the lengths of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ and the length of $\gamma_{-\epsilon}$ tend to the same value, namely the length of $\gamma_0$, a curve in the surface itself, which we call $\ell$. Hence, we can cancel the length $\ell$ from both sides of the equation. This tells us
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \bigg(\mathbf{E}(\gamma_{\epsilon}(c_{\epsilon}))\cdot \frac{\gamma_{\epsilon}'(c_{\epsilon})}{\|\gamma_{\epsilon}'(c_{\epsilon})\|}\bigg)
&=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \bigg(\mathbf{E}(\gamma_{-\epsilon}(c_{-\epsilon}))\cdot \frac{\gamma_{-\epsilon}'(c_{-\epsilon})}{\|\gamma_{-\epsilon}'(c_{-\epsilon})\|}\bigg)
\end{align}

And finally, as we let the length of the curve $\gamma_0$ shrink to $0$, i.e as we let $\ell\to 0^+$, the points $\gamma_{\epsilon}(c_{\epsilon})$ converge to the original point $p$ on the surface. This allows us to deduce
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}^{\parallel}_{\text{top}}(p)&=\mathbf{E}^{\parallel}_{\text{bottom}}(p).
\end{align}
Finally, since the point $p$ on the surface was arbitrary, it follows $\mathbf{E}^{\parallel}_{\text{top}}=\mathbf{E}^{\parallel}_{\text{bottom}}$ at all points of the surface.

---

To recap, the main idea is to simply use the (first) mean-value theorem for integrals. Then, we take the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$ first (i.e shrink the height away from the surface first), and then let the lengths of the curves approach $0$, so that we converge to our original point $p$. Finally, since $p$ is arbitrary, we deduce the equality of the tangential components just above and below the surface.

Finally, I should remark that even though I tried to make this argument more explicit, this is still nowhere near complete/rigorous from a strict mathematical sense. There are still several issues: first of all, we cannot prove any regularity statement without being explicit about the level of regularity of the fields involved. Next, this argument is playing pretty fast and loose with limits. How do we know that all these points actually converge correctly and that the various limits exist and so on. Also, we can only discard the contribution from the other two sides of the rectangle assuming the electric field doesn't blow up like crazy near the surface and blablabla. These issues can only be rigorusly addressed if we carefully specify the various function spaces everything belongs to. Well, I don't really feel like tackling these issues because it's definitely not appropriate at this situation, and this kind stuff is more carefully treated in a PDE text.

But I hope this answer clarifies the main issue: the electric field is not constant along the curve, and it cannot be assumed to be constant along the curve. Rather, one is using the mean-value theorem. And after that, we let $\epsilon\to 0^+$, and finally we have to let $\ell\to 0^+$ (this is the step which Griffiths doesn't seem to mention, but it is necessary to ensure that the points $\gamma_{\epsilon}(c_{\epsilon})$ and $\gamma_{-\epsilon}(c_{-\epsilon})$ converge to the same point $p$).

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. When writing the dot product between $\mathbf{E}$ and the unit tangent vector, that only tells that the component of $\mathbf{E}$ along the curve is continuous(?) To generalize it to both components of $\mathbf{E}$ tangent to the surface the exact same derivation can be done but with the loop oriented in any direction right?

Comment: @QED yes, we do this for any tangential direction. More precisely, suppose $S$ is the surface, $p$ a point on $S$, and $v\in T_pS$ is a vector tangent to the surface. Then, we can find a smooth curve $\gamma:[-1,1]\to S$ in the surface with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, i.e $\gamma$ passes through the point $p$ with velocity $v$ "the direction". We can now "go outward" by $s$, by considering $\gamma_s(t)=\gamma(t)+s\nu(\gamma(t))$, where $s$ is a sufficiently small parameter, and $\nu$ is the unit normal on the surface.

Comment: The loops vary with $p$ (the "center of the loop") and $v$ (the "orientation/direction" of the loop), and $s$  controls the "separation from the surface" (positive means "above" and negative means "below").